# What were Johnny Cash's Last Words?

Tags: reference-request, johnny-cash

Johnny Cash is widely considered to be the greatest country music singer of all time. His death in 2003 shocked thousands. I have done lots of research on the final days of Cash online, and I cannot find out what his last words were.

The only thing that I have found was only a rumor. His last words are rumored to be:

> "I hear the train a comin'."

Is this true, or were his final words something else?

Answer (score -1):

Johnny Cash said "you know when I die, I want my last words to be memorable. I want my last words to be there forever." A few weeks later 'Folsom prison blues' came out, so I believe that those were Johnny Cash's last words because that just can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Can you add a source for this?